# VM can`t connect to SQL server on Windows Azure

Tags: windows-server-2012, azure, jira

I'm trying to install Jira on my VM ( Windows Server 2012 ). Installation went well but I face a problem when I'm trying to connect to an external SQL server which is on Azure too. When I am testing the connection I receive a `"Connection was closed"` error message. It seems that they can't communicate.

Could anybody suggest something? I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe you have any idea on this problem ?

Comment: Define "External database server". If that is a VM the usual "set up your firewall and configure the sql server connectivity options accordingly" applies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. 
The thing is that Windows Server 2012 VM doesn't have Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server. This driver is needed for communication between VM and MSSQL Azure server. 
So i downloaded drivers and everything worked for me. 
You can find drivers at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724.aspx

Answer (score 1):

On **Windows Azure** your VM have to be allowed to connect to SQL server. As I'm supposing VMs is remote machine, so you have to allow **IP address** of your VM to connect with SQL Server.

Comment: I did that. Still

Comment: Hm. Could You provide full error, if applicable? Also make sure that any FireWall is not blocking Yours Jira installation